# How to use Angular2 CheckboxControlValueAccessor?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Can anyone help me to implement CheckboxControlValueAccessor  in Angular2? Can anyone share some example to use CheckboxControlValueAccessor?

I have a JSON that retrieve from an API
i.e.

```
{"prefer":[{"name":"Send me Offers and Letters","preferenceId":"OffersAndLetter","selected":"Y"},{"name":"Need monthly reports","preferenceId":"monthlyReports","selected":"N"}],"comments":null,"status":"SUCCESS","errorDetails":[]}
```

Now i need to create a component and associated template that dynamically create form/checkbox field and access the selected value as N or Y. I also required to track the selection changes by user as well.

The Component file is:

```
@Component({
selector: 'ae-preferencesdata',
moduleId: module.id,
templateUrl: './preferences.html',
directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, ControlMessages],
providers: [SavePreferences]})

export class PreferencesComponent {
public editPreferencesForm: any;
OffersAndLetter: boolean;
monthlyReports: boolean;

public _preferencesValue: Preferences = new Preferences();
constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder, private _router: Router,
    private _routeParams: RouteParams, public _editService: EditPreferences) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.editPreferencesForm = this._formBuilder.group({
        'OffersAndLetter': this.OffersAndLetter,
        'monthlyReports': this.monthlyReports
    });
}

public populatingFields() {
    if (this.OffersAndLetter !== undefined) {
        this._preferencesValue.OffersAndLetter =
            this.OffersAndLetter === true ? 'Y' : 'N';
    } else {
        this._preferencesValue.OffersAndLetter = $('#OffersAndLetter').val();
    }
    if (this.monthlyReports !== undefined) {
        this._preferencesValue.monthlyReports =
            this.monthlyReports === true ? 'Y' : 'N';
    } else {
        this._preferencesValue.monthlyReports = $('#monthlyReports').val();
    }
}

public savePreferences() {
    this.populatingFields();
    let resp = this._editService.updateSchemePreferences(this._preferencesValue, workFlowStepCode,
        parseInt(this._workflowActivityNo));
    resp.subscribe(
        data => {
            if (data.status === 'SUCCESS') {
                formSubmitted = true;
            }
        },
        error => {
            let errorText = error.text();
            this._serverError = error.text().replace(/"/g, '');
        }
        });
}

public updateField(data) {
    let targetID = data.target.id;
    if (targetID === 'OffersAndLetter') {
        this.OffersAndLetter = data.target.checked;
    } else if (targetID === 'monthlyReports') {
        this.monthlyReports = data.target.checked;
    }

}

private setDefaultValues() {
    this.OffersAndLetter = undefined;
    this.monthlyReports = undefined;
}}
```

The template snippet is like:

```
< td *ngFor="let subattribute of prefer" >< input  type="checkbox" name="{{subattribute.preferenceId}}{{subattribute.name}}" id="{{subattribute.preferenceId}}"
(change)="updateField($event)" class="i-checks m-l-mds" [value]="subattribute.selected"
></ td>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please improve your question. It's unclear what your question is about. The question should contain code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish and where you're stuck. Please check the help menu about how to ask good questions.

Comment: I have modified the content based on your input. If you need i can create a JSfiddle as well.

Comment: Then please post the code of the component you try to build and information about where you failed.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have updated it with component and the template

Comment: What's the problem with this code?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

**Use this way for get selected checkbox value in Angular2:**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'checkbox',
    template : `
    <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let chk of chkArray">
        <input type="checkbox" (change)="selectChk($event,chk.id)" />
        <span>{{chk?.title}}</span>
    </li>
    </ul>
  `,
})

export class CheckboxComponent{ 

    private chkSelected: Array<any>=[];
    private chkArray:any = [
        {id:1,title:'title1'},
        {id:2,title:'title2'},
        {id:3,title:'title3'}
    ];

    selectChk(event, val){
        if(event.target.checked === true){
            this.chkSelected.push(val);
        }else{
            var index = this.chkSelected.indexOf(val);
            this.chkSelected.splice(index, 1);
        }
        console.log(this.chkSelected)
    }

}
```

Comment: But this answer doesn't show how to user `CheckboxControlValueAccessor`